# Does the Dual Wielder feat work with the Armorer's Thunder Gauntlets?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, artificer

Can you do this to do bonus action attacks as an armorer?

The Dual Wielder feat grants the following:

> You gain a +1 bonus to AC while you are wielding a separate melee
> weapon in each hand.
>
> You can use two-weapon fighting even when the one handed melee weapons
> you are wielding aren’t light.

The Thunder Gauntlets are described as follows:

> Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon while
> you aren't holding anything in it, and it deals 1d8 thunder damage on
> a hit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes, each gauntlet is an individual melee weapon.

The Thunder Gauntlets state:

> Each of the armor's gauntlets counts as a simple melee weapon

This indicates that each gauntlet is individually a simple melee weapon, each wielded in one hand.

The rules for two weapon fighting state:

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you're holding in the other hand.

Since the Dual Wielder feat makes it so that the weapons do not need the light property, you may use a bonus action to make an additional attack with the Thunder Gauntlets via Two Weapon Fighting.

Comment: I wonder if there's a meaningful distinction between *holding* the gauntlets and *wearing* them.

Comment: @RedOrca Wouldn't the important bit be _weilding_ versus _wearing_? I would definitely read the gauntlets' text as _"…counts as wielding a simple melee weapon…"_ since this is more about making the language work than about the rules. It seems to me, that you just need *some* verb in the text of Dual Wielder.